# A line starting with "Bash:" comes when my terminal opens.pls help me to fix this problem

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

```
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
bash: /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash: No such file or directory 
r@r-HP-250-G1-Notebook-PC:-$
```

A line starting with "Bash:" comes when my terminal opens.

Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: remove `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` from your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thank u for ur replay.

Comment: That has been rectified

Comment: Can you provide out put of `tail ~/.bashrc` ?